# Scale images with canvas without blurring it

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, html5-canvas

I have a class named `Engine.Renderer`. It just creates a new canvas and give me the possibility to easily update and render the active canvas' scene. When a new canvas is created, I apply those settings to its context:

```
this.context.imageSmoothingEnabled       = false;
this.context.mozImageSmoothingEnabled    = false;
this.context.webkitImageSmoothingEnabled = false;
```

In CSS, I've added those lines:

```
main canvas {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;

    image-rendering: optimizeSpeed;
    image-rendering: -moz-crisp-edges;
    image-rendering: -webkit-optimize-contrast;
    image-rendering: optimize-contrast;
    -ms-interpolation-mode: nearest-neighbor
}
```

I have also write a function that adjusts the canvas to the window:

```
[...]
resize: function () {
    var width  = window.innerWidth;
    var height = width / 16 * 9;

    if ( height > window.innerHeight ) {
        height = window.innerHeight;
        width  = height * 16 / 9;
    }

    if ( width > window.innerWidth ) {
        width  = window.innerWidth;
        height = width / 16 * 9;
    }

    width  = Number( width ).toFixed();
    height = Number( height ).toFixed();

    this.canvas.style.width  = width  + "px";
    this.canvas.style.height = height + "px";

    this.container.style.width  = width  + "px";
    this.container.style.height = height + "px";
    this.container.style.left   = ( ( window.innerWidth - width ) / 2 ) + "px";

    // the new scale
    this.scale = ( width / this.canvas.width ).toFixed( 2 );
}
[...]
```

Now, I have a class named `Character`. This class is able to create and render a new character on the given canvas. The render part looks like this:

```
context.drawImage(
    this.outfit,

    this.sprite    * this.dimension.width,
    this.direction * this.dimension.height,

    this.dimension.width,
    this.dimension.height,

    this.position.x,
    this.position.y,

    // set the character sizes to normal size * scale
    this.dimension.width  * this.renderer.scale,
    this.dimension.height * this.renderer.scale
);
```

I have two problems with it:

1. the game performance is even worse than before (~9 FPS when rendering a single character on ~1400x800px canvas);
2. character' image is not so much blurred as before, but I still can see a little blur;

How can I solve those problems?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using integer values for positions and sizes:

```
context.drawImage(
    this.outfit,

    this.sprite    * this.dimension.width,
    this.direction * this.dimension.height,

    this.dimension.width,
    this.dimension.height,

    this.position.x|0,          // make these integer
    this.position.y|0,

    // set the character sizes to normal size * scale
    (this.dimension.width  * this.renderer.scale)|0,
    (this.dimension.height * this.renderer.scale)|0
);
```

Also, setting canvas size with CSS/style will affect interpolation. From my own tests the CSS settings for interpolation does not seem to affect canvas content any longer.

It's better, if you need a fixed small size scaled up, to set the canvas size properly and instead use scale transform (or scaled values) to draw the content:

```
this.canvas.width  = width;
this.canvas.height = height;
```

**Update:** Based on the comments -

When changing the size of the canvas element the state is reset as well meaning the image smoothing settings need to be reapplied.

When image smoothing is disabled the browser will use nearest-neighbor which means best result is obtained when scaling 2^n (2x, 4x, 8x or 0.5x, 0.25x etc.) or otherwise "clunkyness" may show.

A **[modified fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/epistemex/VsZFb/2/)**.

Comment: When I modify directly the size of canvas (without modifying its CSS style) I get +10 FPS, but the image is very blurred, so I think the image smoothing was correctly set to false and everything worked well. .. So should I think the performance decrease is also normal?

Comment: @Bartek hard to tell without seeing the code with HTML markup. If possible, could you set up a fiddle? Don't need to put the whole game there, just the parts which do the drawing and which shows up blurry.

Comment: Voila - http://jsfiddle.net/VsZFb/1/ - Try to resize the result' tab and compare with - http://jsfiddle.net/TYUUJ/24/

Comment: @Bartek ok. I simplified the scaling calculation a bit but the most important part is that when you change the size of the canvas element its state is reset. This means you need to set image smoothing again each time. Also, when using nearest neighbor the pixels may appear clunky at scale factors not in the 2^n range. See if this is what you're after: http://jsfiddle.net/epistemex/VsZFb/2/